# How to share immutable configuration data with hyper request handlers?

Tags: rust, hyper

I am trying to develop a hyper based server application in Rust. There is an INI file holding configuration like binding IP, database and so on.

I don't want to parse the INI file on each request and it is OK to keep the configuration data until server restart. How can I give a struct of already parsed data to the request handler?

I have tried several approaches like using `std::sync::Arc`, but the only thing working so far is to use a `static`, but I want to avoid `unsafe` blocks.

Here is a complete (non working) example:

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "demo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
hyper = "0.12"
rust-ini = "0.13"
```

**demo.ini**

```
[Demo]
value="some value"
```

**src/main.rs**

```rust
extern crate hyper;
extern crate ini;

use hyper::rt::{self, Future};
use hyper::service::service_fn_ok;
use hyper::{Body, Request, Response, Server};
use ini::Ini;
use std::sync::Arc;

pub struct Config {
    pub value: String,
}

fn request_handler(req: Request<Body>, config: &Config) -> Response<Body> {
    let user_agent = req.headers()["user-agent"].to_str().unwrap();
    println!("user agent: {:?}", &user_agent);
    println!("config value: {:?}", &config.value);
    Response::new(Body::from(""))
}

fn read_ini(config_file: &str) -> Arc<Config> {
    match Ini::load_from_file(config_file) {
        Ok(c) => {
            let demo_section = c.section(Some("Demo".to_owned())).unwrap();
            let value = match demo_section.get("value") {
                Some(v) => v,
                None => {
                    println!("Error reading ini");
                    std::process::exit(-1)
                }
            };

            Arc::<Config>::new(Config {
                value: value.to_string(),
            })
        }
        _ => {
            eprintln!("CRITICAL: Could not open config file: {:?}", &config_file);
            std::process::exit(-1)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let cfg = read_ini("demo.ini");
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:3000".parse().unwrap();

    let server = Server::bind(&addr)
        .serve(|| service_fn_ok(move |req: Request<Body>| request_handler(req, &cfg.clone())))
        .map_err(|e| println!("server error: {}", e));

    rt::run(server);
}
```

**Error**

```
error[E0525]: expected a closure that implements the `Fn` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`
  --> src/main.rs:49:16
   |
49 |         .serve(|| service_fn_ok(move |req: Request<Body>| request_handler(req, &cfg.clone())))
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                |                |
   |                |                closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `cfg` out of its environment
   |                this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `Fn`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two levels of closures in `serve` are to be observed with care.
The closure at the second level (which is passed to `service_fn_ok`), defined with `move`, will attempt to move the only instance `cfg` into it, even before any call to `clone()` is made.
This move cannot be done multiple times without cloning, and therefore the closure will only implement `FnOnce`. This is a case of *double move*: the second closure wants to receive a resource in an environment that only allows it to do that once.

To solve this problem, we want the first closure to receive `cfg`, and clone it each time there.

```rust
fn main() {
    let cfg = read_ini("demo.ini");
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:3000".parse().unwrap();

    let server = Server::bind(&addr)
        .serve(move || {
            let cfg = cfg.clone();
            service_fn_ok(move |req| request_handler(req, &cfg))
        })
        .map_err(|e| println!("server error: {}", e));

    rt::run(server);
}
```